# How to detect difference between HEX String and standard String

Tags: java, string, hex, equals

I have two strings:

```
String a = "\u00E4";
String b = "ä";
```

When I compare them to each other, i get the answer: true.
How to detect the difference?

Comment: It's just a another way to initial a string. How can I initialize a string with a different language's character other than English using my standard English keyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. The `\u00E4` is translated to `ä` at compile time.